# How to do an update mutation using GraphQL in AWS AppSync

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync

I am trying to do an update mutation using GraphQL query inside AWS AppSync, but I can't update the data after running the query.
The query is following:

```
mutation MyMutation($input: UpdateUserInput!) {
  updateUser(input: $input) {
    id
    email
  }
}
```

The query variables:

```
{
  "input": {
    "id": "558505e7-c4fd-4af9-81b1-ac407b324d93",
    "email": "hello@test.com"
  }
}
```

The result:

```
{
  "data": {
    "updateUser": {
      "id": "558505e7-c4fd-4af9-81b1-ac407b324d93",
      "email": "test@test.com"
    }
  }
}
```

Anyone have met the same problem before?

Comment: The main suspect is your `updateUser` resolver.  The mutation's resolver is likely not updating the datasource and/or not returning the expected new values to GraphQL.

Comment: Can I fix this inside aws appsync console? And I want to confirm that if I have any syntax mistakes which cause the problem.

Comment: It depends on what kind of [resolvers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorials.html) you are using.  Resolvers are _"how AWS AppSync translates GraphQL requests and fetches information from your AWS resources"_

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me was that I had DataStore with versioning installed. In order to update a record in this case you have to include the current _version number, like this:

```
{
  "input": {
    "id": "558505e7-c4fd-4af9-81b1-ac407b324d93",
    "email": "hello@test.com",
    "_version" : 4
  }
}
```

I found it in [GraphQL Create, update, delete data docs](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/graphqlapi/mutate-data/q/platform/js/#mutations)